# Moving average using window function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

My dataset is as below:

```
Date              Price     3 Day Moving Average
-------------------------------------------------
2018-08-01         10        
2018-08-02         12       
2018-08-03         11        11    (10+12+11)/3\n
2018-08-04         15        12.67 (12+11+15)/3
2018-08-05         13        13    (11+15+13)/3
2018-08-06         17         ...
2018-08-07         18         …
2018-08-08         20         ..
```

Is this possible using just MySQL window functions?

### Environment details:

Server version: 8.0.12 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Comment: Yes. Do Read: [Frames in Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Window Functions with Frames](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-frames.html):

```
SELECT
    Date,
    Price,
    CASE WHEN 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) >= 3 THEN 
             AVG(Price) OVER (ORDER BY Date 
                              ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND 
                                           CURRENT ROW) 
         ELSE NULL 
    END AS avg
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Date;
```

### DB Fiddle Demo

**Details:**

- `2 PRECEDING` means two rows above the current row (excluding the current row). We explicitly define Ascending order on `Date`. So that would means two closest dates, lower than the current row's date
- `CURRENT ROW` means the current row.
- `BETWEEN` allows us to consider the rows in the defined range (including boundary conditions).
- Since, [you want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52868097/moving-average-using-window-function-in-mysql/52868216#comment92650179_52868216) moving average to be `null` for the first two rows, we can check for this using `Row_number()` function in [`Case .. When`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)

Comment: I used the same query to get the avg, but my requirement is that the first 2 rows should have null values, in other words the average calculation should start from the 3rd day.

Comment: @bchain Please edit your question and mention this explicitly there

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, without window functions:

```
select @priceLag := 0, @priceLagLag := 0;
select Date, price, (priceLagLag + priceLag + price) / 3 MovingAverage
from (
  select @priceLagLag priceLagLag, 
         @priceLag priceLag,
         @priceLagLag := @priceLag,
         @priceLag := price,
         price , date
  from tbl
  order by date
) a
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fi4DNdP4bsgHhdrX5vcZ5e/0)